# How can I allow a non administrator domain user account to enable/disable their network adapter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy

I have many users in my company domain (mycompany.org) who are using Dell laptops running Windows 7 Professional.

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 as a domain controller. On priority, my users need to enable / disable their network adapter (it's a requirements of the organization). Currently, the system denies them this privilege without an administrator password. A prompt is displayed every time to request credentials when trying to do this.

Is there a way to give them permission to enable / disable their network adapter requiring an administrator password?

**Steps that I have already taken are:**

1. My domain user (student13) running Windows 7 Professional on a laptop was added to the user group `Network Configuration Operator` on the Domain controller.
2. On the domain controller, a GPO with `Ability to enable/disable a LAN Connection` set to `Enable`.
3. The created GPO above was linked to an OU that contains the users who needs to enable / disable their network adapter.

I believe what I need to do is make sure that my users are part of the `Network Configuration Operators` user group. This group enables the privileges to be delegated to the users so that they can manage the configuration of networking features.

I have tried all the possible solutions. But still, my users are not able to enable / disable their network adapter. A screen to provide credentials appears every time.

Answer (score 1):

Adding them to the `Network Configuration Operators` user group on their workstation. **i.e. local user group (and not on the server)** should help.

You can do this:

1. via the UI using the Computer Management snap-in.
2. via the following command (remember to run the command prompt
   windows as administrator): `net localgroup "Network Configuration Operators" /add <user name or user group name>`

You may want to make sure any group policies that you applied related to this are removed. You can view group policies applied to a workstation using the `rsop.msc` snap-in or using the command prompt:

To find all the policies that are applied to your user account, you would use the following command:

```
gpresult /Scope User /v
```

If you are looking for all policies applied to your Computer, all you need to do is change the scope:

```
gpresult /Scope Computer /v
```

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks...